How does one load Spring Boot application.properties from AWS S3 for spring default configs?
We are migrating Spring Boot applications from on-premise to Amazon Web Services. Spring Boot application.properties are currently present in the on-premise server. We are going to put in AWS S3 and read properties from there. The properties file contains

db connection details - These details are used in code. I can read it manually from S3 and pass it to the application code.
SSL-related details - These details are not used anywhere in code. Where can I pass these details in the application code.
server port, context path - These details are also not used anywhere in the code. Where can I pass these details in the application code?


You could register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean which programatically downloads the properties file from S3 and then adds its properties:
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
        "<AWS accesskey>", 
        "<AWS secretkey>"
    );
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    File file = new File("/tmp/foo.properties");
    s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucket-name", "object-id"), file);

    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = 
      new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/tmp/foo.properties"));
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}

Obviously you should keep the AWS access and secret key in a separate file and not hardcode them into code - this just an example so you see how it works

Can you please add the code snippet little clear. s3Client.getObject is not used anywhere.

not sure what u want me to clear up - getObject is called so that the file is downloaded
